# How to avoid tap on accessory button in table view cell when selection is not allowed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selection

I have my table view that displays cells with some content and a custom accessory button.

When i tap a cell, a 5s work is launched. I don't want the user to tap a cell while the background work is not finished, so i do:

```
self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

It works fine, the user can't tap a cell.

I used to do:

```
self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

But i want to scroll my table view while working in background. The issue is that i also can tap on the cell's accessory button.

How to avoid that not losing the table view scroll?

I could do:

```
- (void)didSelectAccessoryButton:(UIButton *)pButton onEvent:(id)event{
    if(self.tableView.allowsSelection){
        //Usual accessory button code
    }
}
```

But the accessory button highlight would still be there, meaning at some point i'd need to do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
[accessoryButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:NO];
```

I just wish the `allowsSelection = NO` avoids the tap on accessory button too... So what's the better way ?

Comment: I don't think there is a `better way` is your case. `[accessoryButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:NO];` is already a good way, I think. By the way, what about hiding the accessory buttons while your background process is completed? Anyways, they will be useless till the process is completed. Just a suggestion. Good Luck!

Comment: why don't you stop `userInteractionEnabled` to `accessoryButton` until your background task complete ? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way i've found is to combine this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //...
    tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    [tableView reloadData];
    //...
}
```

with this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //...
    accessoryButton.userInteractionEnabled = tableView.allowsSelection;
    //or cell.accessoryView.userInteractionEnabled = tableView.allowsSelection;
    //
}
```

And when the job is done, `self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;`.

What bothers me with this solution is the need to check inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as to do so i also need to reload data; but in the end it's just 3 lines.

Thank you @virus for the simple *"userInteractionEnabled to accessoryButton"* idea.